# signed or unsigned subtraction in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

The signed subtraction with borrowing is rather confusing in x86 assembly. Consider the following words

```
X = 3A12 H
Y = 4023 H
```

I wrote the following code

```
   data1   dw 3a12h
   data2   dw 4023h
   data3   dw ?
   ;------- THEN --------
   mov al, byte ptr data1
   mov bl, byte ptr data2
   sub al, bl                ; 12-23 = EF while carry=1
   mov byte ptr data3, al
   mov al, byte ptr data1+1
   mov bl, byte ptr data2+1
   sbb al, bl                ; 3A-1(carry from sub)-40=F9 while carry=1
   mov byte ptr data3+1, al
```

Now what is stored in the data3 is `F9EF` while the Carry flag is 1. We as **humans** now that result is negative. In other words, the result is actually `-0611 H`. But the computer doesn't know that...

Next, in other instructions it will treat `F9EF` as a positive number. Isn't that correct? How x86 know that `F9EF` is a negative number?

You may say that the sign bit is 1. OK... Then if I want to use `F9EF` as a positive number (or unsigned), how should I tell him?!

Comment: x86 assembly does not care about how you interpret the data, especially the signness. It just runs the instructions. You have to use the appropriate ones for what you need to do with the data.

Comment: Can you explain with an example? So, it's the programmers duty to care that. But how?

Comment: Well for example you can use instructions to perform the two's complement  to retrieve 0611H from F9EFH

Comment: Is that `NEG` instruction?

Comment: Well, you know if I enter two numbers in the program, then I know the result and will put necessary instructions to handle the result if it is negative. But assume, the program receives two number from the user. Then when should I perform two's complement and when should I ignore that?

Comment: You as the programmer (or some other person who wrote the requirements for the program) decide the valid range of inputs for your program. If you decide that you will accept signed 8-bit values (-128..127) and the user enters 200, you should be able to detect that the value is out of range while converting from string to integer. Then you can take the appropriate action (e.g. displaying an error message to the user).

Comment: Do you know what two's complement is?

Comment: Read **[Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt)** for signed vs. unsigned.  (linked from the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)).

Comment: another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276790/how-does-assembly-code-know-if-a-value-is-signed-or-unsigned